# Error while remove migration and update database entity framework core Exception while reading from stream

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first-mapping

I am working in dotnet core web api using restful service with entity framework code first approach. I am running one migration and when I run the migration using add-migration command then I get build succeeded but then when I try to update-database or rollback the migration using remove-migration I get the below error:

```
 PM> remove-migration
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while reading from stream
 ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlReadBuffer.<>c__DisplayClass34_0.<<Ensure>g__EnsureLong|0>d.MoveNext()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlReadBuffer.<>c__DisplayClass34_0.<<Ensure>g__EnsureLong|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass160_0.<<DoReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Authenticate(String username, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<<Open>g__OpenLong|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.GetAppliedMigrations()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.RemoveMigration(String projectDir, String rootNamespace, Boolean force, String language)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.RemoveMigration(String contextType, Boolean force)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.RemoveMigrationImpl(String contextType, Boolean force)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.RemoveMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Exception while reading from stream
```

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved. I had a Factory class in which the connection string was not updated to my local database. There it was pointing to dev and my secret.json was pointing to localhost.